# Distinct Users Information and Limited by records count query

Tags: sql, oracle, exists

I have two tables: `User_Id` and `Shopping` tables:

```
Shopping Table (10000 records)
----------------------------
User_Id | Purchased_Items_Id
1       | 1
1       | 2
2       | 4
2       | 6
....

User_Id Table (7000 records)
-------------
User_Id
1
2
3
....

My_Desired table
 User_Id | Purchased_Items_Id
    1       | 1
    2       | 4
    2       | 6
   .....
```

> My_Desired table must contain 7000 distinct user and totaly its record
>   count should be 8000.

Shopping table is main table. My_Desired table must contain 7000 distinct user and totaly its record count should be 8000. Select 8000 random record from Shopping table and it will contain all distinct `User_Id` at least once.

```
INSERT INTO MY_SHOP
( SELECT S.* FROM Shopping S WHERE User_Id IN (SELECT * FROM  User_Id) AND  ROWNUM<=8000);
```

This code returns 8000 records but distinct `User_Id` count is less than 7000.

How could I fix it ?

In fact there is no other shopping info

Comment: oh, I understood now. I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will return random 8000 shopping info but will contain all 7000 users.

```
select * FROM(

    SELECT user_id,  
         Purchased_Items_Id,
         row_number() over (partition by user_id order by dbms_random.value) as rnk
    FROM 
          USER_ID join Shopping using(user_id) 
    ORDER BY rnk

)

where rownum <= 8000
```

Comment: "This query will return random 8000 shopping info but will contain all 7000 users."

exactly I want to do that ! I will try it now

Answer (score 1):

Your desire is not clear. I suppose that you want 8000 random users, and some info from Shopping...

```
select user_id, 
       first_value(Purchased_Items_Id) over (partition by user_id) some_info --some shopping info
       wm_concat (Purchased_Items_Id) all_info -- all info
from 
   (select user_id, rownum rn
    from User_id
    ORDER BY dbms_random.value
    )
    join Shopping using(user_id)
where rn <= 8000
```

What do you want to be in second column? what shopping info?

Answer (score 0):

I think, that you have use DISTINCT keyword:

```
INSERT INTO MY_SHOP
(SELECT S.Purchased_Items_Id, DISTINCT(S.User_Id) FROM Shopping S WHERE User_Id IN (SELECT * FROM User_Id) AND ROWNUM<=8000);
```

But I think, that subselect in this case is not necessary, because there is not limit in this SELECT.